# Xamarin Forms Shell flyoutitem tittle color

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the color of option titles and selected option how can i do that?

[image: output]

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Xamarin.Forms Project template is going to put *styles* like `FlyoutItemLabelStyle`, `FlyoutItemLayoutStyle` and `MenuItemLayoutStyle` in the  `Shell.Resources` element of **AppShell.xaml**. These styles, in turn, will have many references to `{StaticResource Primary}` which is a color defined in the `Application.Resources` element of **App.xaml**. I would start by assessing what's happening in those places. *Even if you're not using the template* you can study it as an example of how to achieve your outcome.

---

**Device Themes can adversely affect these settings**

What I've noticed is that Xamarin UI elements with default transparent background color may not respond dynamically if the device is, for example, changed to dark mode. (I've definitely seen white text on an effectively-white background in dark mode). So one must pay attention to what the consequences will be when the device's visual themes change. There is an especially good training on this topic by Xamarin guru James Montemagno. I would highly recommend his YouTube video on [Dynamic App Themes in Xamarin.Forms - Light, Dark, & Custom Modes](https://youtu.be/4w8TQ8njd3w)

---

For the purpose of a basic demonstration of how to modify these themes, I have hardcoded "Magenta", "Blue" and "Green" in the default xaml which produces the colors shown in the image that follows.

```
<Shell.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLabelStyle" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Magenta"></Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style Class="FlyoutItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{x:OnPlatform UWP=Transparent, iOS=White}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Blue" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style Class="MenuItemLayoutStyle" TargetType="Layout" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter TargetName="FlyoutItemLabel" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Green" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Shell.Resources>
```

[image: magenta blue green]

Comment: Hi Thanks for answer,
When I was implement your solution I got one error [link](https://prnt.sc/_fKbHqvHC4-u) I think its about App.xaml what can i do for solve this error? @IVSoftware

Comment: It's looking for this entry in the **App.xaml** file: `<Color x:Key="Primary">#2196F3</Color>` and it goes under the `<ResourceDictionary>`  element. Again, this is just the way the Xamarin project sets it up. Here, I uploaded the basic project to GitHub so you can [Clone or Browse](https://github.com/IVSoftware/flyout-item-styles-hard-code-color.git) the source. Hope this is useful!

Comment: Wherever you see something like `Value="{StaticResource Primary}"` in your xaml it's looking up the value of a key named **Primary** in that dictionary and using whatever value is stored there. The reason for doing this is to be able to use these theme colors throughout the project, but be able to change them in a single location.